# Kotlin. Java break alternative for when construction

Tags: java, kotlin, break, kotlin-when, kotlin-1.7

I need `break` like in Java from `when` branch. From Kotlin 1.7.0 I get error

> when expression must be exhaustive

Now I need to add a branch `else`. Inside `else` I want to just exit from `when`.

I can use a return, but in this case, all the code after the `when` block will not be executed and we will exit the entire function. Here is an example:

```
   private fun testFun(a: Int) {
        when(a) {
            5 -> println("this is 5")
            10 -> println("this is 10")
            else -> return 
        }
    
        println("This is end of func") // this will not call
    }
```

I gave this code snippet as an example. The problem is relevant when using `when` with enums or boolean.

I can also use this construct: else -> {}. But it doesn't look very clear to me. Please tell me if there is any way to perform default: break; as we did in Java.

Comment: How about not having an `else` at all?

Comment: When using enum inside `when`  block from Kotlin 1.7 we need to add else branch or branches with all elements of the enum

Comment: Your `when` expression returns `Unit` so a couple of options are `else -> {}` and `else -> Unit`. The example with `Int` is a bit misleading because the compiler won't enforce exhaustiveness in that case.

Comment: @testivanivan Huh, you're right. Weird that I didn't find this in the spec. But the example in your question uses an `Int` though.

Comment: Java's `break` from switch statements is the default behaviour in Kotlin, you don't need `break` in any branch. If you really need to express "do nothing" you can use `Unit`

Comment: gpunto, Yes, you are right, my example is not entirely correct and confusing. But in this case, the Unit suits me,  thanks for the help.

Comment: FWIW, I see nothing at all wrong with `-> {}` — for me, it's clearer than any of the alternatives so far (including `-> Unit`, which is more long-winded and a little harder to follow, especially for non-experts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need an `else` here, as this is a `when` statement, with the bound value being an `Int`. It *would* need to be exhaustive in situations like this

```
val someValue = when(a) {
    5 -> "this is 5"
    10 -> "this is 10"
    else -> "something else" // now you need the "else" branch
}
```

So you don't have to write `else -> {}` in the first place.

That said, if you desperately want to write the word `break` in here for some reason, you can define:

```
val `break` = Unit
```

Now you can do:

```kotlin
// yes, this means you can also do "else -> Unit"
// but if you find "else -> {}" unclear, "else -> Unit" will probably be even more so
else -> `break`
```

This is super confusing though, since `break` in Kotlin has type `Nothing`, rather than `Unit`. Do this at your own risk.

Comment: Did you mean `Nothing` instead of `Never`?

Comment: @Joffrey Yes, thanks! I confused it with the bottom type in Swift. Silly me.